# How i can change my location in same country on selenium fireFox Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geolocation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to change my location inside country using firefox selenium, It's posible ?
I search many on internet i didn't find any thing regard to this problem, just i undrestand using proxy but proxy change on diffrent country not diffrent location inside countery.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem while writing a functional test with Selenium. Here is the solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# geolocation supported, allowed and location mocked
ffOptions= webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
ffOptions.set_preference('geo.prompt.testing', True)
ffOptions.set_preference('geo.prompt.testing.allow', True)
ffOptions.set_preference('geo.provider.network.url','data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 51.47, "lng": 0.0}, "accuracy": 100.0}')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=ffOptions)
webdriver.get('https://www.where-am-i.net/')
```

Comment: but how we can lat and lng put as variable ? i try use format but i cannot success